# Change default _path method name used by link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, link-to

I really like the short link_to syntax:

```
link_to "Ad", ad
```

But by default, that tries to use the ad_path method, which doesn't exist because its nested under magazine. The correct path to use is magazine_ad_path

This still works fine:

```
link_to "Ad", magazine_ad_path(ad)
```

But I feel like calling magazine_ad_path is redundent because the heirarchy is defined in my routes.

ad belongs_to magazine and magazine has_many ads

Any idea how to change the default method in routes, or elsewhere?

Short "pithier" syntax is the 2nd example here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Edit:
Sorry I wasn't clear on my URL structure. It needs to be /magazine/5/ad/12. I know the magazine's id is technically not needed because of the foreign key in Ad, but thats how they want the URL.

Heres my routes.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :magazines do
    resources :ads do
      member do
        get :info, :preview, :send, :fetch
        put :publish
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please paste here relevant routes.rb parts so we can see what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You can write links like below in namespaced resources:

```
link_to "Ad", [:magazine, ad]
```

Or if it is a nested resource:

```
link_to "Ad", [magazine, ad]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a :as option for your route definition so:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads, :as => :ads
end
```

May do the work.

**EDIT:**

After checking the situation, the above answer will not work. Alternatively you could just add `resources :ads` to your routes.rb (apart from the nested declaration you already have).